# Do I need a 300mbps router if my Internet speed is only 10Mbps?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

so this is something that's been bugging me a bit, the advertised 150/300/450/etc. on routers. From what I've read, the huge 150/300's manufactures like to write on their router boxes refer only to the LAN speed? If that's true, then it doesn't matter if I get a 150 or 300mbps router if I don't do any pc-pc transferring then right?

I always thought that if i had for example Internet speeds of 100Mbps, a 150mbps (~20Mbps) router would throttle me.

Thanks

Comment: You've just answered your own question... However, don't forget that companies such as VirginMedia (in the UK) have up to 200MBps fibre broadband so, in reality, a 150MBps router would be under-rated for the company's claims... yes, that speed is the LAN internal speed, but if the Internet speed is faster then your router would be the bottleneck

Comment: @BigChris sorry, bear with me here, so, are the router measurements in Mpbs or mbps (i see it written both ways so it's bloody confusing)? so you're saying the 150/300 is not only referring to LAN pc-pc transfer speeds, but the actual speed coming from the router from the modem? in other words, if i have 200Mbps Internet speeds, i should be looking for a 300**Mbps** router?

Comment: gotcha, so the maximum speed the router can dish out after picking up the signal from the modem is the whatever advertised. ie. if i have Internet speeds of 200Mbps but a 150Mbps router, i'd only get 150 max, and if i have Internet speeds of 100Mbps, an upgrade from a 150 to 300Mbps router would do me no good

Comment: `mbps` or `mb/s` is technically "_milli bits per second_"... though it's used everywhere to mean `Mbps` or `Mb/s` - "_mega bits per second". `MBps` or `MB/s` (capital B) is "_mega bytes per second_". Network bandwidth is typically measured in bits /sec (little `b`), where as disk I/O is measured in bytes /sec (capital 'B'). 8-bits per byte. @Kinnectus is incorrect in using MBps, and actually means Mbps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worse that that, actually. The "Large-print advertised speed" is the HALF-Duplex "air-bit speed" on the WiFi including all the WiFI overhead. Only one side can talk at any given time.

i.e. "300 Mbit" is, to begin with, only equivalent to 150 Mbit on a full-duplex wire. But then it has a bunch of bits that are nothing to do with transmitting your data. 90 Mbit actual throughput is a good day for a "300 mbit" WiFi device under perfect conditions.

For so long as your incoming connection is 10 Mbit you should be adequately served by any 802.11(g) [54 Mbit half-duplex air speed] or 802.11(n) [150, 300, etc. half-duplex air speed] access point.

**If you had 100 Mbit internet**, a "150" would definitely throttle you - as would a "300", to a lesser extent.

Answer (score 1):

The wifi speed that the routers vendors advertise is always the speed in the LAN and under perfect conditions (being near the router, no outside interferences, etc.).

Having those speeds is useful if you have for example, client devices that use files on a server as usually happens on work environments, or if in a home environment you have a multimedia server and clients that use streaming to access the multimedia content.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you do with your wireless - if you use it to stream data to your NAS drive, or videos to your TV, a higher throughput might make a lot of sense. If you only ever use it to connect to the internet, there is little gain from being faster up to the router.

Answer (score 0):

150/300/300 Mbps is the Wi-Fi speed for PC-to-PC transfer that actually influences wireless LAN connectivity only.
Your Internet coming to WAN port is limited to 100 Mbps usually (there are some rare devices with 1 Gb WAN port).

So, anyway, there is no difference for you, as you are not interested in LAN speed.

Comment: thanks, this just made me really sad:[. why do i feel so cheated by those ads now lol. what you're saying is, there's no point in getting more than 100Mbps Internet speeds from my provider unless i get those rare devices you speak of?

Comment: For you, any old router will do, only difference will be marginal range increases. For users with 100Mb VDSL/200Mb Cable/1Gb FTTH then they make a big difference. My connection is 120Mb so a dual band N300 unit is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Need? No. But it might be very nice.

E.g. your 300 Mbps wireless can manage up to 300 Mbps when talking to the AP. There is some overhead, but as long as you sit within a few feet of the AP you should be able to reach speeds close to it. Which is pure overkill if all you do is browse the Internet. A cheaper wireless G (54Mbps) will do almost as well.

> then it doesn't matter if I get a 150 or 300mbps router if I don't do
>   any pc-pc transferring then right?

Correct as long as you only use a single laptop and as long as you are near the AP.

This no longer holds if:

1. Multiple devices become active. If you transfer data from laptop A to a server (or a NAS or a apple timemachine or sync a phone wirelessly or ....) then the bandwidth gets shared.
2. And as long as you are near the AP. Speeds drops off per distance and 50Mbps from a 300 Mbps Ap is not bad when you are not in the same room as the AP. That is still more than then you need, but the speed reduction depends a lot on your house and how it is build.

Answer (score 0):

The transfer rate mentioned on the boxes of the router is the maximum amount of data that your router can handle.

> From what I've read, the huge 150/300's manufactures like to write on their router boxes refer only to the LAN speed.

The above assertion is **incorrect** because if your ISP does provide 300 Mbps, then you would be able to access the internet using your router at a data rate of 300Mbps. Since in your case, the ISP provides only **10Mbps**, it only means that you aren't using the full potential of your router's advertised 300Mbps.

Aside that, one can also connect 2 computers to the router using LAN cables and transfer data between them. If both the computers have a 300Mbps LAN card say, then the 2 computers can transfer data between them through the router at a maximum speed of 300Mbps or **37.5MB** per second.

Comment: What you're saying is what I thought, either i'm terribly misunderstanding people or that half the people are saying that the transfer rate mentioned on boxes won't really affect my Internet speed;\. I don't do any pc-to-pc stuff, I just have 2 laptops and a couple phones hooked up to the router that don't interact with each other whatsoever. By the way, I always thought Mbps was megabytes/s whereas mbps was megabits. Bottom line, IF my service is 200Mbps and my router is 150Mbps, am I getting shafted by my router? Yes/no?